# Eclipse cannot resolve Spring 3 mvc schema

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.2.6 and trying to use the   tag. The problem is Eclipse seems not to be able to find the mvc namespace.
Here is my  XML:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
```

I have tried without the version "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd" and it still does not work.
Eclipse cannot auto-complete "mvc". If I try to run it anyway I get a "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'." error, which I've googled for and did not help much.

The aop and context prefixes can be completed and I have the spring-webmvc-3.2.6.jar in my classpath.
Any help would be really appreciated.Greetings,Alexx

Comment: I suggest you check if you are behind some corporate firewall that could prevent eclipse from checking the remote xsd resources

Comment: No, that's not it. I can see the schemas listed in Window > Preferences > Network Connection > Cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is problem with your xsi:schemaLocation of mvc.

Change `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc` to

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I really should have seen it before. I guess I had tunnel vision. Sometimes it is just better to leave alone for a while.

Comment: You are welcome. Accept the answer if it works, so that it will help other to find the correct answer easily ..... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use STS it will save your time http://spring.io/tools/sts

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

this is i am currently using in my application try this...